# SELECT query with if statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following example information in a PHP script:

```
Custid Name Type Date
1      Roy  A    20150715
1      Roy  -C   20150715
2      Bart B    20150715
```

In my `SELECT` query I only want to get the customers with `type = A and type = B` but if `type = -C` then I want to remove `A` or `B` from my query.

Comment: if what you want is `if(count(type))>1 where type=-C` run query1, else run query 2, then I don't think it is possible to do only with mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to select all records for customers that don't have type '-C' on *any* row then you first need to find the customers that you want to exclude. This can be done with the following query:

```
SELECT Custid FROM yourtable WHERE `type` = '-C';
```

Now you should be able to find all other customers:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
 WHERE custid NOT IN (
  SELECT Custid FROM yourtable WHERE `type` = '-C'
 );
```

Above is just one way to achieve this. You can also use temporary table or `JOIN` against the above subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try using self join.

```
SELECT c_details.custid, c_details.name, c_details.type, c_details.date 
FROM customers c_details
INNER JOIN customers c_type ON c_details.custid = c_type.custid
AND c_type.type <> '-C'
```